# Java Springboot Deployment using GitHub

Tags: deployment, github-actions

I am trying to deploy my Springboot App to my Linux VM using GitHub. The deployment itself works, but the GitHub Action does not stop running since the last command executed is still running but should not be stopped. How can I solve this?

```yaml
name: Backend Deployment to Linux VM
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    name: Backend Deployment to Linux VM
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: update and start project
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
          script: |
            kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:8080)
            cd /home/github_deploy_backend
            cd backend-P2cinema
            git pull
            mvn clean package
            nohup java -jar target/*.jar &
```

Comment: Do you mean that the SSH session is not closed after the script is completed?

Comment: Yes, the SSH session will only be closed if I stop the GitHub Action or kill the started Springboot process manually.

Comment: Right. Did you try to run it with [`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html)?